# Can a process be adiabatic and isobaric? Or Isovolumetric? Or isothermal?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

For example if an adiabatic container with an adiabatic piston, receive energy, by for example some resistence inside the container, and it temperatures change, in order to obtain the final volume, knowing the thermodynamical state at begin, if I use the descrition of adiabatic process I get some volume and if I iso the isobaric processo description I get another value of value, in which one may I trust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your system consists of single component, single phase substance, then its thermodynamic state is completely determined by specifying any two of its state variables. Therefore, a process cannot occur if two thermodynamic variables are held constant.

Isobaric process means pressure is kept constant, isochoric means volume is kept constant, and isothermal means temperature is kept constant. If you keep only one variable constant, you have the option to vary any other thermodynamic variable and so a process can occur.

Adiabatic process in itself does not require constancy of any thermodynamic variable, and so you can have a process which is adiabatic+isobaric, or adiabatic+isochoric, or adiabatic+isothermal. If the process is *reversible*, then adiabatic implies that entropy is constant, and then you cannot have any of the aforementioned processes. Hope this clears up the way to make sense of whatever your original problem was.