# An example of an adiabatic isobaric process

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

I was studying and came across 
" ...process that was adiabatic as well as isobaric... " .
My doubt is that if a process is adiabatic it means that no heat exchange is possible so all we can do is work on the system, but if we do that the pressure would change. So how can one have an adiabatic isobaric process in the first place? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Partially already answered in: 
[Can a process be adiabatic and isobaric? Or Isovolumetric? Or isothermal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288832/can-a-process-be-adiabatic-and-isobaric-or-isovolumetric-or-isothermal)

(an observation to his answers is IF he is talking about ideal gases than only IF the mole number is held constant than specifying two parameters determines the state)

As an example you can have an ideal gas that is inside an isolated chamber with a piston and some weight above it. The weight and the piston will make sure the pressure stays the same, thus isobaric. If you create a small leak for the gas (very small) so that few molecules pass per second, and then closes it. Since there where no change of heat the process is adiabatic. So Isobaric + adiabatic.

If you want to held the mole number constant and still isobaric + adiabatic you can't do it. At least not in an ideal gas, but totally possible in other thermodynamic system.

Comment: There is comment to your question where a Chet Miller says its impossible to have a a "reversible adiabatic isobaric process", and that's true. But the process I told you is not reversible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what work interactions and processes you allow.

1. If you allow only mechanical (pressure) work and a reversible process then fixing the external pressure with an adiabatic wall means that the independent natural equilibrium parameters are the internal system entropy and pressure, i.e., the thermostatic equilibrium functions are given as $U=U(S,p), T=T(S,p), p=p(S,V)$, etc. Since both $S,p$ are given you must also have all the other parameters $U,T,V$ fixed, as well. No process is allowed.
2. If you start the system in non-equilibrium then the system could relax to its equilibrium with constant external pressure and an adiabatic enclosure to a minimum of the internal energy $U$. This of course means that internally the entropy *will* increase, the process is irreversible.
3. If other interaction is also allowed, say, an external electric field and the molecules have dipole moments, then the external bias field can also be used for work interaction and the system's state can be changed accordingly be it reversible or irreversible.